# How to use overloaded function from smart contract with wagmi?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js

So I have two function with the same name but different parameter in my solidity smart contract
`functionName(args1)`
and
`functionName(args1, args2)`

And because of this function overloading, the ABI of the smart contract has 2 function with exactly the same name, `functionName` with 1 argument and `functionName` with 2 arguments

When I try to use wagmi useContractWrite to call the first function with:

```
const functionWrite = useContractWrite({
  ...ContractInstance,
  functionName: 'functionName',
  args: [args1],
});
```

or calling second function

```
const functionWrite = useContractWrite({
...ContractInstance,
functionName: 'functionName',
args: [args1, args2],
});
```

It seems wagmi didn't detect the function because of the duplicate name and it gave me this error:
`'functionName' doesn't exist in interface for contract "{my contract address}"`

Does anyone know how to use overloaded function with wagmi?

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for this and just did some trial and error to figure it out. Since I got it working, I figured I would come back and give you and others an answer.

```
const functionWrite = useContractWrite({
    ...ContractInstance,
    functionName: 'functionName(arg1Type, arg2Type)',
    args: [args1, args2],
});
```

This should pass the function signature to the underlying ethers call.